# Command to collapse all sections of code?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, is there a command to collapse/expand all the sections of code in a file?

Comment: If anyone still happens to look for this info (13 years later, in 2022), please visit [https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) - and try out Ctrl+K Ctrl+0 (this is the digit 0/zero) to "fold" (ie, collapse) all. Unfold using Ctrl+K Ctrl+J.

Answer (score 3379, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> will collapse all.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will expand all. (in VS 2013 - Toggle All outlining)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> will expand all and disable outlining.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> will collapse/expand the current section.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> will collapse all even in Html files.

These controls are also in the context menu under Outlining.

Right click in editor -> Outlining to find these controls.
(*After disabling outlining, use same steps to enable outlining.*)

***For outlining options***: Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Outlining for outlining options.

[image: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Outlining]
[image: Right-click > Outlining menu]

Comment: You can also right click in the editor an select:
  Outlining -> Toggle All Outlining

Comment: I love CTRL +M +P  We have an id**t that nests regions 4 deep.

Comment: ctrl+m ctrl+o is "collapse to definitions" which doesn't work when editting an xml file. For me ctrl+m ctrl+l expands all and collapses all (as toggle), but not always. I have one file open where it works and one where it only expands all, but not collapse all. Both are xml files. No idea why.

Comment: Just to inform (though this is pretty old): ctrl + m + o only collapses all FUNCTIONS, not the classes (or regions etc).

ctrl +m + L will toggle expanding, collapsing everything.

Comment: Ctrl + M + M works on selected text too.  For instance, in a completely collapsed xml document with your cursor on an element Ctrl + M + M will expand that node but not its children.  If you highlight through the closing tag Ctrl + M + M will expand all of that element's children too.

Comment: For what it's worth, these work in Visual Studio 2012 as well

Comment: In VisualStudio 2013 ctrl+M+L toggles collapse state, ctrol+M+O doesn't do anything (HTML VIEW)

Comment: Collapse: `Magic -> Obfuscate` and Expand: `Magic -> Look` Just a helpful acronym to help me remember the hotkeys... It's the best I could come up with, but it works!

Comment: One specific method when I collapse all stays expanded, anybody know why?

Comment: Thx, why this is the first place i saw CTRL+M + M.  Just an extra note, Depending on what is highlighted, is what it will open, Function Name - just function - nothing thats collapsed inside of. Highlight all function code - will open and collapse all the highlighted text.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, collapsing regions via shortcut is disabled by default. To enable, check Tools > Options > Text Editors > c#> Advanced > Outlining > Collapse #regions when collapsing to definitions.

Comment: @gkon - They also decide to change it to Ctrl + M + Ctrl + L (extra ctrl) ugh

Comment: VS2017 Community Edition , C++ code ... almost works. Lambdas are ignored. But. CTRL+M+M works as advertised.

Comment: Highlite a section of code with within a With xxx  End With and hit CNTRL + M then CNTRL + H and it will add its own special code collapse

Comment: works in vs community 2022.  Also  huge thanks.... i have always wanted regions to collapse.  To date I had not noticed the 'Collapse Regions'  checkbox.  Soooo nice.

Comment: to make this extra clear; when everyone say ctrl+m+something else it is actually ctrl+m and then press that key. Example: Ctrl+M then O. This happens in Visual Studio 2022 for C#. I'm not sure why it would be different for anything else, but just in case.

Answer (score 203):

**The following key combinations are used to do things:**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> →
Collapse / Expand current preset area (e.g. <kbd>M</kbd>ethod)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> → Collapse / <kbd>H</kbd>ide (Expand) current selection

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> → C<kbd>o</kbd>llapse all(Collapse declaration bodies)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> → Collapse <kbd>a</kbd>ll

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>  → E<kbd>x</kbd>pand all

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> →  Togg<kbd>l</kbd>e all

There some options in the context menu under Outlining.

Comment: Ctrl-M,L is Toggle all, but definitely the Ctrl-M,A and Ctrl-M,X are the ones I was looking for...

Comment: Very nice idea to remember easily.

Comment: how can you have "ctrl-M-M" ??  There is only one M key.

Answer (score 119):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> expands all

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> collapses all

In the MSDN article ["Default Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio,"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.140).aspx) see the section ["Text Editor"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.140).aspx#bkmk_TextEditor) if you're looking for other shortcuts - these 2 are just a few of the many that are available.

Comment: As I commented in the top answer, ctl+m+o collapses to definition which doesn't work for xml files. ctl+m+l should toggle it, but for me it sometimes does and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Normal pages the crtl+m+o collapse, the JScript outling is backwards, for mine, crtl+m+o expands, and the crtl+M+l expands.

Answer (score 44):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> expands region.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> collapses region.

Comment: But it is only useful command when using js outlining extension, and I have 1000+ lines js file, this shortcut is a** saver!

Comment: AND WORKS FOR XML! WOOO HOOO!! (+1 purely for technical reasons; i'd gladly pay you some rep :) This is going into my regular cheatsheet

Answer (score 35):

- Fold/Unfold the current code block – <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Unfold all – <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- Stop outlining – <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- Fold all – <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Answer (score 29):

In Visual Studio 2017, It seems that this behavior is turned off by default. It can be enabled under **Tools > Options > Text Editors > C# > Advanced > Outlining > "Collapse #regions when collapsing to definitions"**

Answer (score 28):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> collapses all

works for me, whereas

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

does not

Answer (score 25):

Press

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Then

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

To compress all, including child nodes, in XML-files.

Comment: Terse and useful

Answer (score 18):

In Visual Studio 2013:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> collapses all

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> expands all

Answer (score 16):

If you mean shortcut then

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>: This one will collapse the region your cursor is at whether its a method, namespace or whatever for collapsing code blocks, regions and methods. The first will collapse only the block/method or region your cursor is at while the second will collapse the entire region you are at.

http://www.dev102.com/2008/05/06/11-more-visual-studio-shortcuts-you-should-know/

Answer (score 14):

Are you refering to the toggle outlining?

You can do:
<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> then <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to toggle all outlining

Answer (score 14):

Below are all what you want:

- Collapse / Expand current Method

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

- Collapse / Expand current selection

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

- Collapse all

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

- Expand all

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

To collapse all use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

All shortcuts for VS 2012/2013/2015 available at http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/

Answer (score 4):

None of these worked for me. What I found was, in the editor, search the `Keyboard Shortcuts` file for `editor.foldRecursively`. That will give you the latest binding. In my case it was <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. This is probably the latest shortcut that works

Answer (score 3):

if you want to collapse and expand particular loop, if else then install following plugins for visual studio.

- [VS2010](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Skybladev2.Coutline)
- [VS2012](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Skybladev2.Coutline2012)
- [VS2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Skybladev2.Coutline2013)
- [VS2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Skybladev2.Coutline2015)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Collapse All** - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>M</kbd>  + <kbd>O</kbd>

**Expand All** - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>M</kbd>  + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

In case of ugrading to Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013 or 2015, there's a Visual Studio extension to show current registered keyboard shortcuts, [IntelliCommand](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/83f59659-abc1-4bfa-9779-42f687af0481).

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio can help you find the answer to your question in a couple of different ways.

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to access [Quick Launch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh417697.aspx), and then enter "collap". Quick Launch will display something like:<sup>†</sup>

```
Menus (1)
    Edit -> Outlining -> Collapse to Definitions (Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O)
NuGet Packages (1)
    Search Online for NuGet Packages matching 'collap'
```

From there, enter "outlining" to find other menu entries related to outlining:

```
Menus (5)
    Edit -> Outlining -> Toggle Outlining Expansion (Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M)
    Edit -> Outlining -> Toggle All Outlining (Ctrl+M, Ctrl+L)
    Edit -> Outlining -> Stop Outlining (Ctrl+M, Ctrl+P)
    Edit -> Outlining -> Stop Hiding Current (Ctrl+M, Ctrl+U)
    Edit -> Outlining -> Collapse to Definitions (Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O)
Options (4)
    Text Editor -> Basic -> VB Specific (Change outline mode, Automatic inser...
    ...
```

However, note that Quick Launch will show you *only* those commands that are available as Visual Studio menu entries. To find other keyboard-related commands related to collapsing sections of code, in the Visual Studio menu bar click:

```
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard
```

This will display the keyboard section in the Options dialog box. In the "Show commands containing" text box, enter "edit.collap". Visual Studio will display a list that is something like:

```
Edit.CollapseAllincurrentblock    
Edit.CollapseAllOutlining           Ctrl+M, Ctrl+A (Text Editor)
Edit.CollapseBlockcurrentblock
Edit.CollapseCurrentRegion          Ctrl+M, Ctrl+S (Text Editor)
Edit.CollapseTag                    Ctrl+M, Ctrl+T (Text Editor)
Edit.CollapsetoDefinitions          Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O (Text Editor)
```

You'll need to click each command to see its associated keyboard shortcut.

---

<sup>†</sup> My examples taken from Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019:

Go to Tools > Options > Keyboard.

Search for **Edit.ToggleAllOutlining**

Use the shortcut listed there, or assign it the shortcut of choice.

Answer (score 0):

In short, through "Tools … Settings":

[image: In short through tools settings]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For outlining options: Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Outlining for outlining options.

There's an option for regions.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>: Fold (collapse) region

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>: Unfold (uncollapse) region

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>: Fold (collapse) all subregions

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>: Unfold (uncollapse) all subregions

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>: Fold (collapse) all regions

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>: Unfold (uncollapse) all regions

Ref: [Link](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to `collapse/expand` an area within a `class/method` (instead of collapsing the entire `class/method`), you may create custom regions as follow:

```
 #region AnyNameforCollapsableRegion

 //Code to collapse

 #endregion
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-region)

Comment: This is not at all what regions are for. Regions are for maintainability and readability in code and should be used to group like methods, classes, etc.