# Expand/Collapse all Regions doesn't work. never did

Tags: visual-studio-2008

As far as I can tell, this never did work as advertised or expected.

Referring to the accepted answer on the [previous posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982677/visual-studio-command-to-collapse-all-sections-of-code),

CTRL + M + L does NOT expand all, in fact, I've tried ALL of the Outlining menu options and NONE of them expand all, at least for me using VS 2008 in a VB project.

Must I resort to some sort of Macro?

Comment: I have similar problems with CTRL + M + O in VS2010 Ultimate - C++ and C# - please add tags