# Collapse all inactive preprocessor blocks in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-folding

I am working with some third-party code that has a lot of conditional macros.  Visual Studio is quite good at detecting the inactive code, i.e. code wrapped in `#if`...`#endif` that won't be compiled and I can manually collapse these individually.

I would like to hide the inactive blocks automatically - all of them.  Is this possible?

EDIT: is this possible with VS2012? May be a reason to upgrade.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982677/visual-studio-command-to-collapse-all-sections-of-code?rq=1

Comment: @SridharKritha Not the same question. There is an element of seductiveness to this question, the one linked is a solution to collapse all, regardless of whether or not the block is active

Comment: I feel like this is a well-formed question. Sad to see the responses from 2012 seem to be off the understanding. I would guess it's not possible without making a new VS extension.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a way to automatically *collapse*, but there is definitely a setting to *hide* inactive blocks.

The setting is under Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->View

From there, just change "Show Inactive Blocks" to False.

[image: Screen capture of C++ settings for Visual studio Editor]

Comment: If you set this to true, you can have inactive blocks be colored differently, like opacity 10.

Setting this to False will make no difference whatsoever. ;)

Comment: gulgi is right.  The setting "Show Inactive Blocks" is really controlling the question "Should blocks of Inactive Code be shown differently from active code so that you can *see* that they are *Inactive* Blocks?"  If it is changed to False, then the opacity options for Inactive Code are grayed out and the Inactive Code will be shown in the same way as active code.