# Visual Studio (2012) - Collapse methods by default?

Tags: visual-studio

My project has a class with several methods, and many of the methods are overloaded. To access any specific method in my large class, I have to scroll for an unusually long time. The class is so big, sometimes finding a particular method can be difficult. I would like to be able to collapse (or fold) some of the methods, so that it is easier to work inside of my class.I was thinking about `#region` but, I will need to have one for each of my methods.

How can I collapse (fold) my methods?

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982677/visual-studio-command-to-collapse-all-sections-of-code?rq=1

Comment: I saw this answer, but I wanted it to be by default, like regions. Also these commands will collapse my namespace.
I took the screen above by going to the definition of the string class, and all methods were collapsed by default.

Answer (score 3):

I think that there isn't a default setting that can do that, although I might be mistaken. There is a shortcut you can use in VS2008, not sure if it will work on 2012, but you might give it a shot.

- `Ctrl + M + O` - collapse all
- `Ctrl + M + L` - expand all
- `Ctrl + M + P` - expand all and disable outlining
- `Ctrl + M + M` - collapse/expand the current section