# how to enable or disable visual studio feature

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

i'm a web developer.

how to enable/disable this  feature  in visual studio?

please see this pic of visual studio:

[image]

Comment: Can you please show your work and possible exception/error message as a text?

Comment: @SonerGönül not in this particular case ;) It's just a screenshot of feature OP wants to switch on/off.

Comment: I do not have any errors.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Since I'm at work now, imgur domain is blocked. So I _can't_ see what is going on exactly :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Advanced
Uncheck checkbox `Enter outlining mode when files open`
For more option check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982677/visual-studio-command-to-collapse-all-sections-of-code)

Comment: It isnt a complete duplicate as the answer only states different shortcut keys But op wanted to disable the feature which wasnt present in that answer.

Comment: yeh .... I need outlining  mode  for HTML tags

Comment: @Jerin - what? it clearly says "CTRL + M + P will expand all and disable outlining."