# Visual Studio 2017 Collapsing Regions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've noticed that in Visual Studio 2017, when I hit CTRL+M, CTRL+O, regions do not collapse to definitions. Has there been a change on this? How do I collapse everything -- including regions?

BTW, I get the same results whether I use the keyboard shortcut or go through the context menu by right-clicking. Regions just do not collapse at all.

Comment: I'm not having this problem. Try checking your keyboard shortcuts - Edit.CollapsetoDefinitions. Maybe you have a different command mapped to that.

Comment: As I mentioned, I get the same behavior if I use the context menu so it's not keyboard mappings. I do have a few minor issues with Visual Studio 2017 and looks like this is one of them.

Comment: Have you tried activity log? Is there error when you collapse region via context menu?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It seems that this behavior is turned off by default. 
It can be enabled under 
**Tools > Options > Text Editors > C# > Advanced > Outlining > "Collapse #regions when collapsing to definitions"**

Comment: Wow! Don't you love it when Microsoft makes these tiny changes that catch you off guard!!! Thank you for getting to the bottom of this!

Comment: This answer should be added to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982677/visual-studio-command-to-collapse-all-sections-of-code?rq=1

Comment: How do we expand all the regions ?

Comment: CTRL + M + L expands all. @AnyaHope link helped.